# Typescript return object key based on input parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function that accepts a name parameter and then use it to create return object property names:

```js
function myFunction (name: string) {
  // ....

  return {
    [`provide${name}`]: {},
    [`consume${name}`]: {}
}

const { provideTest, consumeTest } = myFunction('Test')
```

How should I type this function?

Comment: Interesting, I thought it would be able to figure out type given 4.1 has template literal types.

Answer (score 1):

You can type it like this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBACgJwPYDcCWATKBhJA7AZwFcBbKAeQCMArAHgBUYoAPEKPDAmAkBNPAOYA%20GAF4YAJSgBHImgRQMtAN4wA2gGsoYGPxgAKAAYRk6LABJl9AL6GYAHxiGAxvmJlLNwwEoAugC4YJBooZxAYayEAbmBgADMiPDC0fBgSMAAxROT8BiZWdk5uXn5hfTwAQzJA%20m9AxFRMHDdSChoGEWVgGBgAel6YADphwdiehRAiBDwYLp6etWNTJstKslsA2esAGm75xddCVtWqqA3A5R296xgKrgazZqOyKjp6aOBrWMOeWZg9kyNLD0KA8XY9H6tEFgz5iNKZbIgFJ4fQAcmhIFR3iiQA)):

```js
type ProvideConsumeObj<T extends string> = Required<{ 
  [key in (`provide${T}` | `consume${T}`)]: object 
}>;

function myFunction<T extends string>(name: T): ProvideConsumeObj<T> {
  // ....

  return {
    [`provide${name}`]: {},
    [`consume${name}`]: {},
  } as ProvideConsumeObj<T>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would type it as [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAFGAQ2QFMAuRAZygCcYwBzASnIG8AoRTxAbQA9yqtBgF1WAXwDcbMYnacA9PMQA6VcrYdE1YlBDUkcrtwAGAB2pwAbjAAmxACQtCJMcdGyxAGk2cTEBBQgJI7OxK7uLF6aktIa-mBUsoia5la2xAAqxFTenPGBJFk50ogAvCgYWLAIuADkRVC1jBJAA) :

```
function myFunction(name: string): {
    [x: string]: {};
} {
  // ....

  return {
    [`provide${name}`]: {},
    [`consume${name}`]: {},
  };
}

const { 
  provideTest,
  consumeTest,
} = myFunction('Test');
```

---

Unfortunately, you cannot generate a type based on the value of `name`.

---

As an alternative, you can ask the user to provide the keys, so the returned data would be strongly typed : [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPAFUQFMAPKIsAEwGdFqoAnGMAc0QF47HmWA+ACjABDZEQBcXJqwCUEgN4AoRMsQBtEomaJ8AXXkBfANwL9iRcoD0FxADo7NhUsQMiUEAyTmVqgAYAHBjgANxhKIgASOWFRfR89M30AGidlXwgEahBRSOiiWPi5JKdTIVovVI0tXQNjZSMTR3SwejNEJwDg0KJ8Inpk5SbM0R6+kw4UDCxYBFwAcg6QsJGoWcQAH0RZwazu3pWBWeXZ6UMgA).

In my opinion, the first way is better.

```
function myFunction<T extends string = string>(name: string): {
    [x in T]: {};
} {
  // ....

  return {
    [`provide${name}`]: {},
    [`consume${name}`]: {},
  } as {
    [x in T]: {};
  };
}

const { 
  provideTest,
  consumeTest,
} = myFunction<'provideTest' | 'consumeTest'>('Test');
```